# Property 'clientX' does not exist on type 'Event'.ts(2339) on Rxjs v6.x

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, mouseevent, typeerror

I'm trying to use rxjs for handling a problem which gets the first click on the document when it's clientY is greater than 200px.

the problem is, typescript telling me that clientX is not in the Event type. which you can see below:

[image]

So i tried to set the event type as MouseEvent in the parameter like:

```
(event: MouseEvent)=> ({})
```

but it gave me another error, which it seems that the  problem is with rxjs which cannot detect click event is different from simple event;

[image]

What is the best solution to fix this weird problem?

**Update: the cause and answer:**

[image]

thanks to @Prince

I find out that, fromEvent emits "event type" only, which means it can tell us oh i got an event.

So we should tell it to cast the event as which ever event has been occurred (in this example is MouseEvent), so it can work as we want, like we do with html input types to prevent type error on using value:

```
const search_elm = document.getElementById("search")! as HTMLInputElement;
search_elm.value="10";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with the use of operators ( fromEvent, pluck, filter, first) as follow. Please find inline description.

```
const source = fromEvent(document, 'click')
.pipe(
  map(event => {
    const e = event as MouseEvent;
    return {x: e.clientX, y:e.clientY};
    }),
  filter((obj) => obj.y > 200),
  first(),
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Here is working stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ccrz9x